# mysqldump via terminal Vs mysqldump via phpmyadmin - Performance

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I wanted to know if there is a difference in the method of exporting information when I export a large database through phpmyadmin or through the terminal by mysqldump.

- The runtime is better in mysqldump?

I would like to get pros and cons.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run from the mysqldump command you are improving your system because this is a directly command to mysql, with phpmyadmin the server has to deal with php and apache.